# .NET ConfigurationBuilder - Parse a JSON string stored in an environment variable

Tags: json, .net, configuration, environment-variables

For reasons, I have a json block stored in an environment variable.

For example, I have an environment variable called `Serilog` which contains my Serilog configuration:

```
{
    "Enrich": ["WithThreadId"],
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Override": {
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "System": "Debug"
        }
    },
    "WriteTo": [{
        "Args": {
            "outputTemplate": "redacted"
        },
        "Name": "Console"
    }, {
        "Args": {
            "fileSizeLimitBytes": 52428800,
            "logDirectory": "redacted",
            "logFilePrefix": "logfile",
            "outputTemplate": "redacted",
            "retainedFileCountLimit": 15
        },
        "Name": "RollingFileAlternate"
    }]
}
```

In my app's startup class, I have the following config code:

```
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
```

Currently, what happens is that when the application starts, the `Serilog` environment variable is read, but it is just read as a literal string, and is not converted to proper key-value pairs that the `ConfigurationBuilder` would be expected to produce.

I guess this is because it otherwise expects environment variables to be simple key-value pairs, not complex JSON objects.

For reasons that I'd rather skip, I NEED to make this work.

How can I tell .NET to parse the JSON string stored in the environment variable and use THAT for the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass settings as key-value pairs you will need to set as [separate variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#environment-variables) with `__` instead of json's `:`, when the element structure includes an array, the array index should be treated as an additional element name in this path:

```
Serilog__MinimumLevel__Default=Debug
Serilog__MinimumLevel__Override__Microsoft=Warning
Serilog__Enrich__0=WithThreadId
```

Comment: I don't want to use separate variables. For certain reasons (which I'd rather not go into detail on) I need to read it as a single environment variable.

Comment: @Bassinator AFAIK you can't do this. As workaround you can implement [custom configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-configuration-provider) you read the string from environment variable, parse it as json and expose as  needed.